# .Net C# Remote Method Invocation (RMI) (Client/Server communication)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, client-server, .net-remoting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What the .NET standard for remote method invocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560107/what-the-net-standard-for-remote-method-invocation)

What exactly is **C#** version of **Java RMI**?

I want to invoke the methods of client from the server, ping the client from server etc.

How this server and client communication can be done with c#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the choice between Remoting and WCF

Remoting is the oldest technology but is not deprecated and may be enough for you.

WCF is more recent and has more possibilities (for security, authentication, and message transports and protocols).

You can easily find tutorials for both solutions.